# Select self referencing table with spring data into new object

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have a self referencing employee table. An Employee reports to his immediate lead which also an Employee.

fields->

```
id, name, employee_type, lead_id
```

I have mapped this table into this class,

```
public Class Employee {
   private Integer id;
   private String name;
   private Integer employeeType; // 1-manager, 2-project lead, 3-developer, etc
   private List<Employee> reporters;

}
```

How can I load all managers with his reporters using Spring Data JPA custom mapping? (those reporting employees will have their own reporters)

Mainly, I don't know how to map the corresponding list.

```
@Query("SELECT new Employee(id, name, employee_type) FROM employee")
List<Employee> findAllManagers();
```

Comment: You cannot select a multi-valued field in JPQL, and so you will not be populating your `reporters` field via JPQL constructor syntax

Comment: @BillyFrost is there a workaround to select reporters then?

Comment: Do a separate query